# How do i draw X-Axis, Y-Axis line graphs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was thinking what would be the easiest way to draw X Y axis line graphs on Win Forms. When searched for them I found some prefer to use a component called MS charts which I never heard of. But I want know how do draw X-Axis y-Axis line graphs line below using any easy or standard ways

[Here is an Image of a Line Graph](http://i1267.photobucket.com/albums/jj546/snifusbits/xylinegraph_zps5ce2e3fb.png)

If some one could provide me with informative links to blogs and posts on how draw them or step by step process on how to draw, I would appreciate it : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the thing to use is indeed the Microsoft Chart.

It is available as a download for .Net 3.5, but it is included with .Net 4 via Visual Studio 2012 or later.

See here for more details:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: im using VS 2012 ultimate version have you tried to install it on VS 2012 were there any issues?

Comment: @user3296223 You shouldn't need to install it - it should already be installed. If you are in the Windows Forms designer and go to the Toolbox and look a the Data section, there should be something called "Chart" there. That's what you want.

Comment: (I updated the link to a better tutorial!)

Answer (score 0):

MS Chart is one of the possible way, which is free. There are other options from various companies and they may not be free.

If you are using MS Chart what you need is Line type chart:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Try following links:

1. [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=14422)
2. [A Guide to using MSChart for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET)
3. [Samples Environment for Microsoft Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

3rd links gives the source code for a sample application. Hope this helps.